# ggsurvplot : legend number at risk

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I produced the following life curves with ggsurvplot :

[image]

However, I can not display the same colors for the Number at risk legend as for the curves.Also, do you know if it is possible to display the lines instead of the legend for the number at risk (solid or dotted)?

Thank you very much for your help !

below is the code I used to obtain the result :

```
subjid <- 1:n

status_os <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE)
time_os <- ifelse(status_os==0, rnorm(n,mean=365, sd=30), rnorm(n, mean=180, sd=30))

groupe <- sample(c(1,2), n, replace=TRUE)
mutation <- sample(c(1, 0), n, replace=TRUE)

data <- data.frame(Identifiant=subjid, status_os=status_os, time_os=time_os, groupe=groupe, mutation=mutation)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time_os, status_os)~groupe+mutation, data=data)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = data, break.time.by = 12, risk.table = "nrisk_cumevents",
                legend.title = "", legend = c(0.2, 0.2), linetype = c("strata"),
                risk.table.y.text=TRUE, break.x.by = 50)

colors <-  rep(c("red", "red","blue","blue"))
lines <-  rep(c("solid","dashed","solid", "dashed"))

p$plot <- p$plot + scale_linetype_manual(values = lines) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colors)

p$plot <- p$plot / p$table + plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(2, 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "legend" is the axis text of the table plot. And as the style of the axis set is set via the `theme()` one option to set your  colors would be via the `color=` argument for the `axis.text.y` which uses `ggtext::element_markdown` instead of `element_text`.

Note: I added the missing pieces to make your example and data reproducible.

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit,
  data = data, break.time.by = 12, 
  risk.table = "nrisk_cumevents",
  legend = c(0.2, 0.2), 
  linetype = c("strata"),
  risk.table.y.text = TRUE, 
  break.x.by = 50,
  tables.height = 1/3
)

colors <- rep(c("red", "red", "blue", "blue"))
lines <- rep(c("solid", "dashed", "solid", "dashed"))

p$plot <- p$plot + 
  theme(
    legend.position = c(0.05, 0.05),
    legend.justification = c(0.05, 0.05)
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = lines) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = colors) +
  labs(color = NULL, linetype = NULL)

p$table <- p$table + 
  theme(
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(
      color = rev(colors)
    )
  )

p
```

[image]

**EDIT** A quick and easy approach to have lines in the table plot would be to use unicode characters for the y axis labels to fake a line, e.g. [U+2501](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2501/index.htm).

```
p$table <- p$table +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = ggtext::element_markdown(
      color = rev(colors),
      hjust = 0,
      vjust = .6
    )
  ) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    labels = ~ rep(
      c("\u2501", "\u2501\u2501"), 2
    ),
    limits = rev
  )

p
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 100
subjid <- seq(n)

status_os <- sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE)
time_os <- ifelse(
  status_os == 1,
  rnorm(n, mean = 365, sd = 30),
  rnorm(n, mean = 180, sd = 30)
)

groupe <- sample(c(1, 2), n, replace = TRUE)
mutation <- sample(c(1, 0), n, replace = TRUE)

data <- data.frame(
  Identifiant = subjid,
  status_os = status_os,
  time_os = time_os,
  groupe = groupe,
  mutation = mutation
)

fit <- survfit(Surv(time_os, status_os) ~ groupe + mutation, data = data)
```

Comment: Hi Stefan ! Thank you for your answer. Exactly what I expected. Is it possible to replace the legend by solid or dashed lines ? For exemple, for « groupe=1, mutation=0 » it will be a solid red line, a dashed red line for « groupe=1, mutation=1 » … ?

Comment: See my edit for a quick and easy approach. If that does not work for you or does not fit your needs, then there is always the approach to do that via some additional `geom`s which however requires some (or a lot of) additional effort to get it right.

Comment: It is exactly what I need ! Thank you again for your help Stefan.